# Webscraping using python, firefox and geckodriver - getting the external stuff into a .exe build

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox, setup.py, geckodriver

First of all, please excuse the possibly imprecise language used here - I am an old geezer!

I have set up a Python file (call it Job.py) which uses Mozilla Firefox as its browser, which in turn means that executable file geckodriver.exe must reside in a specific location (C:\Anaconda3\Scripts in my case), principally so that it exists in my "Python path", as I understand it.

Now, my intention is to use command "python setup.py build" to build a folder which contains an executable file (Job.exe).  I can do this in such a way that Job.exe will run on a PC as long as it has Firefox installed (and located in the same place as mine is) and geckdriver is in the 'correct' place also on that machine.

At present, Job.py points to a particular file (firefox.exe) which must be found in the specific place on any PC that is going to run it, so the path of choice is explicitly entered into the code.

Is it possible that I could lift a copy of my Firefox installation folder and paste it alongside the Job.py file?  Then I could change my "Firefox path" to be for this copy.  I think this would work.

A bigger problem is with the geckodriver.  How can I best ensure that, rather than the version of geckodriver which lives on a host machine is used, but rather a version somehow embedded into the contents of my build folder is used instead?

Comment: Yes, you can pack your installation of Firefox with your job. You can go through the trouble of configuring Firefox (e.g. where to load the profile?) yourself or download a pre-configured *portable* Firefox installation :) I'm not sure about the geckodriver, sorry!

Comment: Does anyone know how to package geckodriver and how to get the setup.py file (or otherwise) to facilitate its use?